# Lua 5.4 source inclusion Not quite right in c++Builder 10.1

Tags: windows, lua, scripting, c++builder

I have downloaded the latest version of Lua and included the source in to my project in c++builder from Embarcadero. All went rather well. Compiles perfectly.

But when I run my script, that's when it stops working correctly.

This script is ok

```
-- Script
Tp = tonumber( Temp )
Sp = tonumber( Setpoint )
Clr = "0xFF00FF00"
Db = 0.5
Hi = (Sp+Db)+1
Lo = (Sp-Db)-1
f = Hi
--
```

This script fails

```
-- Script
Tp = tonumber( Temp )
Sp = tonumber( Setpoint )
Clr = "0xFF00FF00"
Db = 0.5
Hi = (Sp+Db)+1
Lo = (Sp-Db)-1
f = math.floor( Hi )
--
```

It also fails if I try to use `string.format`, so it looks like the libs have not loaded correctly.

I use `luaL_openlibs()` to load the libraries.

I have come to the conclusion that there must be a compiler directive that I need to use. But I can't find anything that makes any difference.

If anyone has any info on building the source into their own application, I would love to know.

The main reason I have done it this way is for speed.

My Application is a data server that runs scripts against incoming data, and I expect to have several hundred data connections, both in and out.

Comment: Please add the error which describes how script failed - to make sure that it's the problem with `math.floor` and `string.format` absence. And please add the part of the code in which you initialize Lua state and load libraries. At first glance it looks like only base module is loaded but hard to say without exact errors and code.

Comment: I try to read the error, but it returns the filename of the script that I loaded. It's only the return value from lua_pcall that is any indication of a problem. I'll just get the other items and post shortly

Comment: `if (lua_pcall(L,2,0,0)!=LUA_OK) fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", lua_tostring(L,-1));` is usually enough to get the message.

Comment: It's times like this, that I wish the internet could reach out and slap me. Whilst copying the code to paste into here, I notices I had 2 places where libs are loaded. One at the start if there are any scripts available, and a second when someone adds the first script.

I had fixed the second one, but not the first.

Needless to say it's now working perfectly. Time to ramp up the data.

Thank you. If you hadn't asked, I wouldn't have notice ( not yet anyway ).

Comment: There you go. It's the power of writing proper question with good example code. A lot of problems can be solved just with that. Feel free to still update the question and post the answer yourself for future reference (you can accept it and earn some reputation on SO in the process).

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is to call

```c
lua_openlibs( state );
```

and not this code

```c
static const luaL_reg lualibs[] = 
{
  {"base", luaopen_base},
  {"table", luaopen_table},
  {"io", luaopen_io},
  {"string", luaopen_string},
  {"math", luaopen_math},
  {"debug", luaopen_debug},
  {"loadlib", luaopen_loadlib}, 
  /* add your libraries here */
  {NULL, NULL}
};

static void openstdlibs( lua_State *l ) 
{
  const luaL_reg *lib = lualibs;
  for (; lib->func; lib++) 
  {
    lib->func(l);  /* open library */
    lua_settop(l, 0);  /* discard any results */
  }
}
```

I can only assume that there is some path information missing that openlibs has.
Sorry about the formatting, couldn't get it to look right

Comment: This looks like old code from Lua 5.0 (https://www.lua.org/source/5.0/lua.c.html#openstdlibs). For Lua 5.4,see https://www.lua.org/source/5.4/linit.c.html

Comment: Also, it's `luaL_openlibs` not `lua_openlibs`.